# Move a game object between two positions in a sin wave

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, trigonometry

I have two positions in a unity scene and I want a sphere game object to move between them. This is easy enough to do with the move towards command, but what I want to happen is the ball to accelerate when leaving one, then decelerate when approaching the next in a controlled curve. I need it to osculate between the two positions in a manor similar to that of a ball being rolled.

I was told that I could do this with a sin wave, however I'm unsure how. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: If Physics is not important too you then you can use iTween.

Answer (score 4):

## Preamble

There are a number of ways to solve your problem, not only by using sine function.

## Sine function example

Here's an example:

```
public float frequency = 1.0f; // in Hz
public Vector3 positionA;
public Vector3 positionB;
private float elapsedTime = 0.0f;

public void Update()
{
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    float cosineValue = Mathf.Cos(2.0f * Mathf.PI * frequency * elapsedTime);
    transform.position = positionA + (positionB - positionA) * 0.5f * (1 - cosineValue);
}
```

Cosine is used here instead of sine just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with almost the same task. My objects were located in random positions, the line between two of them was not parallel to axis. So, I created common solution which can helps anybody.

Here is [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq4ePbpmEno), source code on [Github](https://github.com/shamanland/unity-sinusoidal-moving).

The script is very simple by itself. All we need to do is calculate two vectors - vector of main direction and orthogonal vector. After this we need to subordinate orthogonal vector by sine function, and then perform addition of these two vectors, so the sum will move object following exact sine curve.

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    float t = Time.time - startTime;
    rb.velocity = direction * speed + orthogonal * amplitude * Mathf.Sin (frequency * t);
}
```

You can find more [details here](http://blog.shamanland.com/2016/03/move-by-sinusoid.html) - how to setup scene, components, etc.